# What is the Max number of Columns allowed in SQL Server 2008 View?

Tags: sql-server-2008

More of a curious question I can't seem to quickly find an definite answer to.

In SQL Server 2008 is there a max limitation on the number of columns that are allowed in a view? From the MSDN article (below) I see that there is a limit of 4096 Columns per Select statement. Would this then be applied to a View?

Example:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[TestView]
AS
SELECT     Column1, Column2 FROM dbo.SomeTableName
```

Would I be limited to 4096 columns in this view?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx

Comment: More than likely if you are coming anywhere close to the limit, your database has some structural flaws.

Comment: Agree in a sense, but, you don't know the context. We are providing an interface with a simplified way for end users to create they own view of certain tables and columns. In theory the end user could potentially create some unmanageable views. I want to make sure we give them the ability to do what they need, but also keep issues to a minimum.

Answer (score 27):

By default of finding an authoritative source, I figured I'd try...

It appears that **the limit is 1024 columns**, that is the case in SQLServer 9.0  (both 'Express' and Enterprise versions).

```
    The error message is:
    Msg 4505, Level 16, State 1, Procedure wvTest, Line 3
    CREATE VIEW failed because column 'Yo1' in view 'vwTest'
                       exceeds the maximum of 1024 columns.
```

Comment: @bogertron  Thanks that was hours of tedious editing!...  (luckily I scripted the making of such a monster ;-) )

Comment: mjv, v9 is 2005.  Do you have access to SQL 2008 to do the same test?

Comment: what about best practice? can i make use of all 1024 columns or should i create new table if i exceed around 100 columns(for example)?

Answer (score 8):

You cannot create more than 1024 columns for a view.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx

how to Test it:

Run these two procedure for creating table with n number of Columns

Stored Procedure 1:

```
CREATE Proc [dbo].[CreateTableWithNColumnsPrefixX]
(@TableName nvarchar(100),@NumofCols int)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @i INT
DECLARE @MAX INT
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @j VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @len int
SELECT @i=1
SELECT @MAX=@NumofCols
SET @SQL='CREATE TABLE ' + @TableName + '('
WHILE @i<=@MAX
BEGIN
select @j= cast(@i as varchar)
SELECT @SQL= @SQL+'X'+@j  +' NVARCHAR(500) , '
SET @i = @i + 1
END
select @len=len(@SQL)
select  @SQL = substring(@SQL,0,@len-1)
SELECT @SQL= @SQL+ ' )'
exec (@SQL)
END
GO
```

Stored Procedure 2:

```
CREATE Proc [dbo].[ CreateTableWithNColumnsPrefixA]
(@TableName nvarchar(100),@NumofCols int)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @i INT
DECLARE @MAX INT
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @j VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @len int
SELECT @i=1
SELECT @MAX=@NumofCols
SET @SQL='CREATE TABLE ' + @TableName + '('

WHILE @i<=@MAX

BEGIN
select @j= cast(@i as varchar)
SELECT @SQL= @SQL+'A'+@j  +' NVARCHAR(500) , '
SET @i = @i + 1
END
select @len=len(@SQL)

select  @SQL = substring(@SQL,0,@len-1)


SELECT @SQL= @SQL+ ' )'

exec (@SQL)

END

GO
```

Create table t1 with 1024 columns using 1st SP.

Create table t2 with 1024 columns using 2nd SP.

Now run the following Query:

```
Create view TestView
As
Select * from t1,t2
```

It will give following error

```
Msg 4505, Level 16, State 1, Procedure TestView, Line 3
CREATE VIEW failed because column 'A1' in view 'TestView' exceeds the maximum of 1024 columns.
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is Microsoft link for complete details....

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx

According to this Microsoft...

```
Columns per nonwide table  | 1,024 
Columns per wide table     | 30,000
```

Answer (score 2):

Even in my SQL Server 2008 R2 (version 10.5) there is a 1024 column limit on VIEWs. Sorry I wish it wasn't so.

My customers consume the data in Excel using PivotTables and PivotCharts. Excel is good at this, IF you feed it with a data warehouse view that contains a row for everything and a column for everything, including the kitchen sink. But SQL server can't store a view with more than 1024 columns, which is a real pain.

Now I have to teach my customers to manually edit the SQL statements behind the data connection properties in Excel. What a nightmare! Very few of them get it. Us programmers are clever, users are dumb, which is why we should (anyone listening Microsoft???) not build in arbitrary limits into our software. Ever.

Comment: I completely agree, but I'd bet it's not so much that they built in an arbitrary limit, but more that the limit is from the days when memory and computers were MUCH more limited, and they just never took the limit out. That's just my guess. :)