# Best list to use when ordering

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I'm extending my question here [Dynamically Creating GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426012/dynamically-creating-gridview) and trying a different approch as suggested, but im stuck again.

I have a table that handles my names and order of key values.

```
KeyNames:
ID Int primary key
KeyName1 varchar(20)
KeyOrder int
KeyName2 varchar(20)
KeyOrder int
...
KeyNameN varchar(20)
KeyOrder int
```

These Keys represent the Name and Order of another table to be displayed in a gridview. ie:

```
 DocumentTable:
 ID int primary key
 PDF_Folder varchar(30)
 Key1value varchar(100)
 Key2value varchar(100)
 ..
 KeyNvalue varchar(100)
```

So in my gridview the user can decide the column names of the Keys and the value (I might want to called Key1 "description" order 1 and Key2 "Names Mentioned" and order 2.

if Order < 0 then it will not be displayed in the gridview.

Im stuck on how I will create a gridview to display each columns for KeyNValue with the colmn name KeyNameN and the order of KeyOrderN..

Comment: how are the keynames & document tables joined ?

Comment: The Document Table has Key1Value.. to Key20Value.. These are the values that the user can put any value they like (they make put description in key1value). the in the KeyNames, they can name that column "Description" and order it 1.. So the KeyNames determins which columns are displayd in the gridview, and the names of the columsn. the values are stored in the KeyNValue..

Comment: As a side-effect, I recommend you to change this logic `if Order < 0 then it will not be displayed` This logic certainly will work but you are mixing the **order concept** with the **display concept** clearly they are two different things. Favor always readability and maintainability, it's better if you have a property called `Enabled` or `Visible` in your entity. Respect the Single Responsibility Principle and your code will become easy to read, write, and maintain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will use the DisplayIndex property of the DataGridViewColumn to set the Order.
You will use the HeaderText property to set the name.
I see you have no rows, so the grid will have just one row with many columns.

So, assuming you have a grid named MyGrid, each column is in a class named MyEntityRecord, you have put all columns in a list and you want to display the data after the user clicks on a button, here is a sample code to be called from the Click Event.

```
void ShowCustomGrid(List<MyEntityRecord> aList)
{
    MyGrid.Columns.Clear();
    MyGrid.Rows.Clear();
    for(int loop=0;loop<aList.Count;loop++)
    {
        MyGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewColumn(new DataGridViewTextBoxCell()));
        MyGrid.Columns[loop].Text=aList[loop].KeyName;
        if(aList[loop].KeyOrder<0) MyGrid.Columns[loop].Visible=false;
    }
    //Now that all columns have been added, change the display index
    for(int loop=0;loop<aList.Count;loop++)
    {
         if(aList[loop].KeyOrder>=0) MyGrid.Columns[loop].DisplayIndex=aList[loop].KeyOrder;
    }
    //Finally, put the values
    MyGrid.Rows.Add();
    for(int loop=0;loop<aList.Count;loop++)
    {
        if(aList[loop].KeyOrder>=0) MyGrid.Rows[0].Cells[loop].Value=aList[loop].KeyValue;
    }
}
```

If I understood correctly, this should do what you wanted.

Comment: I changed this quiet a bit, but it got me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

craete table script : 
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[KeyNames](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [KeyName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [keyOrder] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DocumentTable](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PDF_Folder] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Key1Value] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Key2Value] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Key3Value] [varchar](100) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

==============Key Names Table:Rows======== 

1   PDF_Folder  2 
2   Key1Value   3 
3   Key3Value   5 
4   Key2Value   4 
5   ID  1             
==========================================

==============Document Table:Rows======== 
1   aa      a1  a2  a3 
2   bbb b1  b2  b3 
3   ccc c1  c2  c3 
==========================================

query as per below is generate dynamic order query : 

DECLARE @str_column VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(100);
SELECT @str_column = COALESCE(@str_column + ', ', '') + KeyName
FROM Keynames order by keyorder;
set @query= 'select ' + @str_column + ' from DocumentTable';
exec(@query);